# When does Magento 2 create Order ID?

Tags: magento-2.1

I have to get the orderId on Checkout page (before success page)

```
$checkoutSession = $settingsHelper->getCheckoutSession();
$checkoutSession->getQuote()->reserveOrderId();
$reserveOrderId = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getReservedOrderId();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need `sales_order_place_after` event to get **order_id before success page**

**Create `events.xml` at `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">    
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="md_place_order_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Orderplaceafter" />
    </event>           
</config>
```

**Now create `Orderplaceafter.php` at `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer'**

```
<?php

namespace Magedelight\Subscribenow\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $orderFacory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderFacory
    ) {
        $this->orderFacory = $orderFacory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $lastorderId = $orderIds[0]; // This is last orderId which you want
        $order = $this->orderFacory->load($lastorderId); //load order object
    }
}
```

Comment: pardon the noob question, but how do i use the $order var in execute method? Something like
$x = Orderplaceafter->execute();

Comment: getting an error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Observer\Orderplaceafter::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory,